# ASP.NET Framework form post request and action link tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am in the middle of migrating my ASP.NET core app to ASP.NET framework 471 and I am facing a couple of issues:

1) `.cshtml` form template

ASP.NET Core form page looked like (It was working fine) and calling the `Login` action in the controller

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Enter your username">
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter your password">
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

However, after migrating to .NET Framework upon clicking the submit button it does not call the `Login` action controller and no post request is submitted.

2) Using `@Html.ActionLink`

The following code was working fine in the Core app

```
<ul class="br-sideleft-menu">
    <li class="br-menu-item">
        <a class="br-menu-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Dashboard">
            <i class="menu-item-icon icon ion-ios-home-outline tx-20"></i>
            <span class="menu-item-label">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, the link is not working (not even clickable) when migrating to the framework application.

I am aware that I need to utilize `@Html.ActionLink` component, but I am not sure how to template the above code so that it will include all the tags and classes.

Comment: Oh well, it is a long story, but it is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Enter your username">
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter your password">
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Should be

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Enter your username">
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter your password">
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
}
```

and

```
<a class="br-menu-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Dashboard">
     <i class="menu-item-icon icon ion-ios-home-outline tx-20"></i>
     <span class="menu-item-label">Dashboard</span>
</a>
```

Should be

```
<a class="br-menu-link" href="@Url.Action("Dashboard", "Home")">
     <i class="menu-item-icon icon ion-ios-home-outline tx-20"></i>
     <span class="menu-item-label">Dashboard</span>
</a>
```

As an aside, Core and Framework are completely different. None of your `asp-*` syntax is going to work in Framework.

Comment: For the second part, I am getting `HtmlHelper<dynamic> does not contain a definition of Url`.

Comment: For the first part, I am getting `FormMethod does not contain a definition for POST`

Comment: It should be `Post`. Note: Not all in caps